# How to pause execution until the user logs in for startup app on Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making an app in C++ using Win32 that needs to pause its execution when the session is locked. I've been using `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` to detect `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` and `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` and update my app state which works great. The app needs to start on startup, so I've placed a shortcut of the executable here: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`.

The problem I have is that the app starts its execution before the user logged in since `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` or `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` have not yet been sent. I haven't found anything useful regarding this problem. Any ideas on how I could check that the program is running while the user has not logged in?

Comment: I am not sure how deamons work in Windows, but may be you should look how you proper install a daemon in Windows instead of placing the exe in the StartUp folder. I bet you can then choose between different startup conditions which have to be met before the daemon gets started.

Comment: @JulianH I currently don't have a service (daemon on Linux) since I started the project having in mind I needed some UI for user control. I'll maybe split the project in two having the UI executable control the service if this is the only way.

Comment: your exe start after user log in

Comment: Startup should actually run after you logged on... However, you could put it into Task Scheduler with a Trigger "At log on" (https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows). Beware, you will need to prevent your application from being started multiple times...

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have is that the app starts its execution before the
> user logged in since WTS_SESSION_LOCK or WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK have not
> yet been sent.

When you restart (or turn off then turn on) Windows, startup apps run after the user logs on. So you will not receive `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK`. It is expected because the user has already logged on before your app runs.

To solve this issue, you can query the session information via `WTSQuerySessionInformation` to check if the current session is [active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-wts_connectstate_class) or not when your app starts. Active indicate the user is logged on, so you can start execution of your app.

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSSessionInfo, &sInfo, &BytesReturned);
```

After the Windows started up, you will receive `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` and `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` normally.